# Adding new elements into a custom element dynamically in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I am writing a polymer application which the server will return the image file names upon request. 1 or 2 image file(s) may return. I want to add dynamically generated iron-image element(s) to the shadow dom. I can check that the iron-image element is added but image didn't show. Whats wrong ?
"test3.png" is in the same location as the html file already.

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-image/iron-image.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-spinner/paper-spinner.html">

<dom-module id="iron-image_test-element">   
<style is="custom-style">
    paper-spinner               { display: block; position: fixed; top:50%; left:50%; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; }
</style>

<template>
    <paper-spinner id="spinner"></paper-spinner>
</template>

<script>

    Polymer({
        is: "iron-image_test-element",

        ready: function() {

            //Remove server call back for simplicity
            var img = document.createElement("iron-image");
            img.setAttribute("src", "test3.png");
            img.setAttribute("sizing", "contain");
            img.setAttribute("class", "preload fade");
            img.style.width = "400px";
            img.style.height = "400px";

            Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(img);
            Polymer.dom(this.root).flush(); 
        }

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use img.src, this way you access the bound component property rather than the html element attribute.

Here's your example somewhat extended, also exposing the src property to the world outside your element: https://gist.github.com/IgorRubinovich/36bc1ce3a314ed7cf032

See http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html for more.